# How to init Boostrap element or Materialize css in Angular 5 without library?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-bootstrap, angular2-materialize

I am new to Typescript and Angular world. I want to know how we can initialize Boostrap element in Angular way? I mean purely using Boostrap library without ngx-boostrap wrapper.

For example, if I want to init a boostrap carousel. According to the guide, I have to write something like this:

> $('.carousel').carousel()

I wonder how we can init this in Angular way like using **ElementRef** or something?

I tried **@types/jquery**, and the a**bove code just work**, but Angular recommend not to touch DOM directly, so not sure how we will do this

I also looked into ngx-boostrap library, but don't see any init code, so I don't know how it works.

And in ngx-materializecss, it is using @types/jquery and Render (which is now deprecated) to wrap the elements.

I appreciate any help or reference for this matter.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should not be use jquery with angular .Even if you neglect this fact and used jquery with angular , in the long run it is going to create more problems to you in the future

Answer (score 0):

For each component there are a doc with all required steps on how to add, run and live samples.

Carousel doc is here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel